# A question about "It" clause

Tags: grammar

"To obtain deeper insight into lignin biosynthesis and the metabolic network it is embedded in, we used a systems biology approach as defined by Ideker et al"

In this sentence, I'm confused about the clause-- "it is embedded in", is it an attributive clause?

Comment: It's a relative clause with locative meaning, _in which it is embedded_.

Comment: It's a 'bare' relative clause, where the relativised element is missing but understood as complement of the locative preposition "in", i.e. "in x", where x represents the missing relativized element, which  has the nominal "metabolic network" as antecedent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a relative clause.  Grammatically, it would be correct to say:

(1) "To obtain deeper insight into lignin biosynthesis and the metabolic network that it is embedded in, we used a systems biology approach as defined by Ideker et al"

or

(2) "To obtain deeper insight into lignin biosynthesis and the metabolic network which it is embedded in, we used a systems biology approach as defined by Ideker et al"

or

(3) "To obtain deeper insight into lignin biosynthesis and the metabolic network in which it is embedded, we used a systems biology approach as defined by Ideker et al"

But there is a problem, and this might be the source of your confusion--is biosynthesis a thing that can be embedded?  Is this how we think of biosynthesis?  Biosynthesis is a process that is not independent of its environment.

A better statement might be:

(4) "To obtain deeper insight into lignin biosynthesis and the metabolic network in which it functions, we used a systems biology approach as defined by Ideker et al"